# How can I create a motion-blur effect with CSS?

Tags: css

I've got this working nicely on objects with a solid background colour, by applying multiple box-shadows:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqmtkojf/)

html:

```
<div></div>
```

css:

```
div{width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgb(0,150,0);
    box-shadow: -15px 0 12px rgba(0,150,0,0.2)
              , -11px 0 10px rgba(0,150,0,0.4)
              ,  -8px 0  8px rgba(0,150,0,0.6)
              ,  -6px 0  6px rgba(0,150,0,0.8)}
```

This isn't ideal as you get shadow bleeding up and down from the element instead of just to the left, but it kinda does the job.

But what I really want is for it to work nicely with a background image, e.g. in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqmtkojf/1/) I'd like the colours on the edge of the `div` (or the edge of the background image at least) to be stretched out.

How can I do that?  *Can* I?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `::before` then duplicate your element and blur it.

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 100px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/pDj7wo9.png);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: left center;
}

div::before {
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/pDj7wo9.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    content: "";
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think there's any better options for a more streak-like blur, or is this the only thing I can do without creating secondary graphics?

Comment: You could add `scaleX` for a more motion blur like effect. https://jsfiddle.net/rqmtkojf/2/